# How to access vanilla class instance stored from one Vue component in a parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, storybook

I have a parent component with 2 child components that both inherit from the same base component.  (This parent component is being created and used in a Vue Storybook). Both `SiblingAComponent` and `SiblingBComponent` inherit the same `BaseComponent`, and instantiate the same inherited data `classInstance`, which is a vanilla JS class instance from another library. I am trying to access this `classInstance` from the parent component to pass as data into the second sibling component (in this case, from `SiblingAComponent` to `SiblingBComponent`), by using an reference `siblingARef`. However, I get this error from the storybook compiler:

```
too much recursion
isArguments@http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.9107ef8d0bc0558399e1.bundle.js:49010:16
keys@http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.9107ef8d0bc0558399e1.bundle.js:49073:28
_traverse@http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.9107ef8d0bc0558399e1.bundle.js:119972:19
_traverse@http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.9107ef8d0bc0558399e1.bundle.js:119974:28
```

ParentComponent Story:

```
storiesOf("ParentComponent Story", module)
    .addDecorator(
        withKnobs({
            escapeHTML: false
        })
    )
    .add("Passing data from A to B", () => ({
        name: 'ParentComponent',
        components: {
            SiblingAComponent,
            SiblingBComponent,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                siblingAData: [....], // array of objects
                siblingAOptions: {
                    axes: {},
                    height: "50px",
                },
                siblingBData: [...], // array of objects
                siblingBOptions: null,
            }
        },
        mounted() {
          const siblingAInstance = this.$refs.siblingARef.classInstance;

          const newOptions = {
            legend: {
                external: {
                    reference: siblingAInstance,
                },
            },
          };
       
         // this line is where I am getting an error
         this.siblingBOptions = legendExternal;
      },
      template: `
      <SiblingAComponent ref="siblingARef" :data="siblingAData" :options="siblingAOptions"/>
      <SiblingBComponent v-if="siblingBData" :data="siblingBData" :options="siblingBOptions"/>
      `,
}));
```

SiblingAComponent:

```
<template>
    <div class="sibling-a-component"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { ComponentA } from '@libraryexample/components';
import BaseComponent from './base-component.vue';

export default {
    name: 'SiblingAComponent',
    extends: BaseComponent,
    mounted() {
        this.classInstance = new ComponentA(this.$el, {
            data: this.data,
            options: this.options,
        });
    },
};
</script>
```

SiblingBComponent:

```
<template>
    <div class="sibling-b-component"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { ComponentB } from '@libraryexample/components';
import BaseComponent from './base-component.vue';

export default {
    name: 'SiblingBComponent',
    extends: BaseComponent,
    mounted() {
        this.classInstance = new ComponentB(this.$el, {
            data: this.data,
            options: this.options,
        });
    },
};
</script>
```

BaseComponent:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'BaseComponent',
    data() {
        return {
            classInstance: null,
        };
    },
    props: {
        data: { type: [Object, Array], required: true },
        options: { type: Object, required: true },
    },
};
</script>
```

Coming from the Angular and React worlds, using a reference to access a Vanilla class instance from another Component is nothing new, even if it's unconventional. I am new to Vue, so I am wondering why would trying to access a class instance fail (works fine for primitive data types) and give me such a weird error? Where is the recursion occurring?